# Ant Zip task to create a zip named by reading Version.java

Tags: java, ant, build

My Version.java is like

```
public class Version {
 public Version() {
   VERSION_PROGRAMNAME = "application";
   VERSION_MAJOR = "1.7";
  }

public static final String IDENT = "@(#) application: 1.7.77 ";

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(LINE_SEP);
  System.out.println("************* Version Information *************");
  System.out.println(new Version());
  System.out.println("***********************************************");
  System.out.println(LINE_SEP);
}
```

I need to create a Zip file using Ident String(Only 1.7.77 part).I can't change Version.java or add anew property file. So I need to this Ident value and create a zip like applicatipn_.zip using ant.

please help

Comment: You might want to review how Java JARs use Manifest.mf or consider putting this information in a properties file instead of a code file.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather do the reverse.

Put the version number in your build file, as a property. At build time, use the replace ant task to insert the version from ant into the Version.java file, and then compile the application.

This way, you still have only one place where the version is written, and your Version class delivered with the app is identical to the one you have now.

Comment: Surely I would like to do that but I have only one option to read the Version.java file and parse Ident String. Please provide if You have any idea.

Comment: Implement your own ant task which finds the version number in the file using a regexp and sets an ant property. Use the value of this property in the jar task to define the target file name.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by other answers, my first preference would be to control the build number from an ANT property.

## Solution as requested

You've stated in other answers that you need to parse out the version number from the Version.java file.

My solution uses the [groovy ant task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) to set the **version** property:

```
<target name="parse-version">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <groovy>
    def file = new File("src/main/java/Version.java")

    file.eachLine { line ->
        def matcher  = (line =~ /.*String IDENT = "@\(#\) application: ([\.\d]+) ";\s*/)

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            properties.version = matcher[0][1]
        }
    }
    </groovy>

    <fail message="Did not find version" unless="version"/>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="parse-version">
    <zip destfile="build/application_${version}.zip" basedir="dir_to_pack" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use `version.properties` file with following content:

```
version = 1.7.77
```

Ant buildfile `build.xml` has following statement for the purpose of inclusion and usage of values defined in `version.properties`:

```
<property file="version.properties"/>
```

It is possible to use `version` property in order to create zip file:

```
<zip destfile="build/${version}.zip" basedir="dir_to_pack" />
```